# How to "center" SKTexture in SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make Jigsaw puzzle game in `SpriteKit`. To make things easier I using 9x9 squared tiles board. On each tile is one `childNode` with piece of image from it area.

But here's starts my problem. Piece of jigsaw puzzle isn't perfect square, and when I apply `SKTexture` to node it just place from `anchorPoint = {0,0}`. And result isn't pretty, actually its terrible.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2di30hk5evdd5fr/IMG_0086.jpg?dl=0

I managed to fix those tiles with right and top "hooks", but left and bottom side doesn't care about anything.

```
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode()
    let originSize = frame.size
    let textureSize = texture.size()
    sprite.size = originSize
    sprite.texture = texture
    sprite.size = texture.size()
    let x = (textureSize.width - originSize.width)
    let widthRate = x / textureSize.width
    let y = (textureSize.height - originSize.height)
    let heightRate = y / textureSize.height
    sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5 - (widthRate * 0.5), y: 0.5 - (heightRate * 0.5))
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width * 0.5, y: frame.height * 0.5)
    addChild(sprite)
```

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way you can get placement right without knowing more about the piece texture you are using because they will all be different. Like if the piece has a nob on any of the sides and the width width/height the nob will add to the texture. Hard to tell in the pic but even if it doesn't have a nob and instead has an inset it might add varying sizes.

Without knowing anything about how the texture is created I am not able to offer help on that. But I do believe the issue starts with that. If it were me I would create a square texture with additional alpha to center the piece correctly. So the center of that texture would always be placed in the center of a square on the grid.

With all that being said I do know that adding that texture to a node and then adding that node to a SKNode will make your placement go smoother with the way you currently have it. The trick will then only be placing that textured piece correctly within the empty SKNode.

For example...

```
    let piece = SKSpriteNode()
    let texturedPiece = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

    //positioning
    //offset x needs to be calculated with additional info about the texture
    //for example it has just a nob on the right
    let offsetX : CGFloat = -nobWidth/2

    //offset y needs to be calculated with additional info about the texture
    //for example it has a nob on the top and bottom
    let offsetY : CGFloat = 0.0

    texturedPiece.position = CGPointMake(offsetX, offsetY)
    piece.addChild(texturedPiece)

    let squareWidth = size.width/2

    //Now that the textured piece is placed correctly within a parent
    //placing the parent is super easy and consistent without messing     
    //with anchor points. This will also make rotations nice.
    piece.position = CGPoint(x: squareWidth/2, y: squareWidth/2)
    addChild(piece)
```

Hopefully that makes sense and didn't confuse things further.

Comment: The whole thing was about, how to set up puzzle pieces in correct positions. In moment, when I cut image in puzzle shapes, took the center of clipping UIBezierPath frame and later set it as SKSpriteNode position. But thank you for you answer anyway, it will be useful for me latter. :)